# Python: How to iterate and put a certain amount of elements in a list and those lists in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of 2 million vins. I need to break up those 2 million vins in different lists of 1,500 in the following format `"VIN";"VIN";"VIN";"VIN"`.

I'm not sure how to iterate and put these VINs into lists of 1,500 and then those lists into a list.  I ultimately need to iterate over the big list and send each list of 1,500 to an api call in the above format.

I tried this code sample making lists of 3:

```
import pandas as pd
#develop the data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["vin"], data = ['LHJLC79U58B001633','SZC84294845693987','LFGTCKPA665700387','L8YTCKPV49Y010001',
                                             'LJ4TCBPV27Y010217','LFGTCKPM481006270','LFGTCKPM581004253','LTBPN8J00DC003107',
                                             '1A9LPEER3FC596536','1A9LREAR5FC596814','1A9LKEER2GC596611','1A9L0EAH9C596099',
                                             '22A000018'])

df['manufacturer'] = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','D','D']

for i in df:
    list_of_lists = []
    list = []
    df['vin'] = list.append(3)
    list = list_of_lists.append()
    return list_of_list
```

Comment: this code won't compile. You have a return statement but no function or method, also append(3) should not work. Lastly do not use reserved names like `list` for variables

Answer (score 1):

You can split your dataframe using `numpy.array_split`. If you want to split your example into 4 evenly sized chunks, you would do

```
aux = np.array_split(df,4)
```

Output

aux[0]

```
vin manufacturer
0   LHJLC79U58B001633   A
1   SZC84294845693987   A
2   LFGTCKPA665700387   A
3   L8YTCKPV49Y010001   A
```

aux[1]

```
vin manufacturer
4   LJ4TCBPV27Y010217   B
5   LFGTCKPM481006270   B
6   LFGTCKPM581004253   B
```

aux[2]

```
vin manufacturer
7   LTBPN8J00DC003107   B
8   1A9LPEER3FC596536   B
9   1A9LREAR5FC596814   C
```

aux[3]

```
vin manufacturer
10  1A9LKEER2GC596611   C
11  1A9L0EAH9C596099    D
12  22A000018   D
```

Comment: thanks @Yuca.  that gives me a list of four data frames.  How can I pull the VINs out in a `"VIN";"VIN";"VIN";"VIN"` format?